# Splitting Values in XML using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, split

I'm really a newbie to this XSLT world. I am facing a problem of splitting the values present in a single XML node.

For example my input XML contains the following data:

```
<Employee>
  <FirstName>AAA</FirstName>
  <LastName>BBB</LastName>
  <MobileNo>9999999999-6666666666-7777777777</MobileNo>
</Employee>
```

In the above example an employee can have multiple mobile numbers, so all his mobile numbers are merged into a single XML node `<MobileNo>`. A hyphen (-) is used to separate the mobile numbers, meaning `9999999999` is the first mobile number, `6666666666` is the second mobile number, and `7777777777` is the third mobile number. An Employee can have any number of mobile numbers.

Myy output XML should have the following structure.

```
<Employee>
  <FirstName>AAA</FirstName>
  <LastName>BBB</LastName>
  <MobileNo>9999999999</MobileNo>
  <MobileNo>6666666666</MobileNo>
  <MobileNo>7777777777</MobileNo>
</Employee>
```

so how do I achieve this using XSLT 1.0?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is this XML coming from? Fix the upstream logic to create multiple `MobileNo` fields so you don't have to parse it yourself. Where is the XML going to? You could also fix the downstream logic to parse it there where it could be as simple as `split('-')`. In other words, why have you decided to do this using an XSL transform? Also, what is the nature of your self-imposed restriction to use XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 4):

**Here is a complete, shorter and simpler (no `xsl:choose`, no `xsl:when`, no `xsl:otherwise`) XSLT 1.0 transformation that "splits" any number of dash-separated strings:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="MobileNo" name="split">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

  <xsl:if test="$pText">
   <MobileNo>
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText, '-'), '-')"/>
   </MobileNo>

   <xsl:call-template name="split">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '-')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Employee>
    <FirstName>AAA</FirstName>
    <LastName>BBB</LastName>
    <MobileNo>9999999999-6666666666-7777777777</MobileNo>
</Employee>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Employee>
   <FirstName>AAA</FirstName>
   <LastName>BBB</LastName>
   <MobileNo>9999999999</MobileNo>
   <MobileNo>6666666666</MobileNo>
   <MobileNo>7777777777</MobileNo>
</Employee>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Recursively called named template (`split`).
2. The *stop condition* is the passed parameter being an empty node-set/string.
3. Use of *sentinel* to avoid unnecessary conditional instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You must write this as a recursive named template. The code below shows the idea.

The named template `split-mobile` here is passed a string with possible hyphens where the string must be split.

A call to `substring-before` fetches the first number. This will return an empty string (which evaluates to *false*) if the string contains no hyphen.

An `<xsl:choose>` element outputs the first number inside a `<MobileNo>` element and calls `substring-before` with the remainder of the string if it was hyphenated. Otherwise the entire string is output.

```
<xsl:template match="MobileNo">
  <xsl:call-template name="split-mobile" >
    <xsl:with-param name="numbers" select="text()" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="split-mobile">

  <xsl:param name="numbers" />
  <xsl:variable name="number" select="substring-before($numbers, '-')" />

  <xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="$number">
      <MobileNo>
        <xsl:value-of select="$number" />
      </MobileNo>
      <xsl:call-template name="split-mobile">
        <xsl:with-param name="numbers" select="substring-after($numbers, '-')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
      <MobileNo>
        <xsl:value-of select="$numbers" />
      </MobileNo>
    </xsl:otherwise>

  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```